# CanvasRenderingContext2D cannot be append to document (w/ appendChild())

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm making an Ionic4 app that allows basic image manipulation with canvas elements. I'm having trouble displaying the canvas elements. I'm doing this in a loop and dynamically spawning canvas elements so that there can be any amount of images on the page.

I've only been running the app in ionic serve and it seems to be giving the same error across all common browsers.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){

    let numbImages = this.sourceArray.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < numbImages; i++){

      this.imageArray[i] = new Image();
      this.imageArray[i].src = this.sourceArray[i];

      this.canvasArray[i] = document.createElement("canvas");
      this.canvasArray[i] = this.canvasArray[i].getContext("2d");
      this.canvasArray[i].drawImage(this.imageArray[i],0,0);
      document.getElementById("canvasContainer").appendChild(this.canvasArray[i]);

    }

  }
```

The canvas's don't appear in the canvasContainer div and the following error is logged (firefox).

```
ERROR TypeError: "Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node."
```